# Install wordpress Ubuntu problem

Tags: wordpress

I have wordpress already install but when I put this link http://localhost/wordpress/
i see script file :

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: Add more info including what web server software you're using (nginx, apache, etc.) and whether you have PHP installed at all (and if yes how - as an apache module or php-fpm or something else).

Comment: @sledge Hammer  i'm using apach2

Comment: Well, the Wordpress requirements are PHP, MySQL and a web server. So far you've only mentioned the web server (apache), so I'll assume that you don't have PHP installed (and maybe MySQL).  


In order to install PHP itself and as an apache module you have to write the following in the terminal: `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5` If you don't have mysql as well you'll need to install it with `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

Comment: @SledgeHammer i have all install , the probleme is the wordpress doesn't load theme for first time when i put this link http://localhost/wordpress/

Comment: @Bobox - please could you be more clear (via [edit]ing) about the problem? For loading themes you should be able to set it up via the Adminstration Panel - see [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Themes). Make sure you have set up Wordpress properly - if you need help look at https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/wordpress.html

Answer (score 1):

The PHP code is displayed as raw text instead. This is because your PHP module for Apache isn't installed.

Run the following command:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php7.0 
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.0
sudo a2enmod php7.0
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

That should make your lamp working well.

Please do take note that `php7.0` is the default version for Ubuntu 16.04. **You will need to install the latest version of php for future versions.**

Comment: Why not use `php` and `libapache2-mod-php` to let APT choose the best version for the particular Ubuntu release?

Comment: @codycortez, please specify that php7.0 is the default version for Ubuntu 16.04, or that version you are using. Thus in the future, the readers will be reminded they should check which is the current version. I've removed the tag [12.04] from the question, otherwise the answer were incorrect. +1

Comment: @pa4080 oh, yeah thank for the heads up. Will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Check for installed PHP with apache!?
You can create a phpinfo.php  with following content:

?>
copy in our htdocs folder 
And open in Browser!
----stooni