# only one site on server says PHP is missing MySQL extension (nginx)

Tags: mysql, php, nginx, wordpress

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 server with Nginx as webserver. When I try and access one of the sites installed, I receive this error:

"Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress."

I cannot really understand what to do because other sites on the same server work well - so I can't believe it's a problem with a missing module or anything else.

thank you for your help!

Comment: Do the other sites use MySQL, however?

Comment: they are all wordpress sites. in case it helps, the site in question is rsgmedia.info and I added a phpinfo.php file http://rsgmedia.info/phpinfo.php

Comment: Do you use the same php-fpm TCP/Unix socket for all of your sites?

Comment: Have you looked at here? https://askubuntu.com/questions/663887/install-wordpress-ubuntu-problem/992282#992282

Comment: the link is for apache, and I have a nginx server.

Comment: > Do you use the same php-fpm TCP/Unix socket for all of your sites?
I am not sure what it means or how to check it, but I do believe so. It's one server with more sites (all wordpress) on it. They all work, aside from this one